# WPF: How to save a GIF file in a string or file from an URL?

Tags: wpf, string, save, uri, gif

I try to retrieve the content of a .gif located on an URL into a string -and eventually save it to disk-, ran from a WPF appliactions using the webbrowser. After trying dozens of solutions I am not further than I was yesterday. I thought that the code below would do the job, but the saved string cGif contains...the url itself. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.gifbitmapdecoder.aspx I then thought I needed GifBitmapEncoder instead, but the sample suggests that this creates an empty gif instead of a downloaded one.

(PS: what I basically want to do is to retrieve the GIF bytes straight from the WPF webbrowser but I haven't found anything working there either)

```
private void GifSave()
    {
        var uri = new Uri(@"http://www.archivearts.com/GIRAFFE2.gif");
        var Img = new GifBitmapDecoder(uri, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);

        string cGif = Img.ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Modified from a sample on the GifBitmapDecoder MSDN page:

```
// Open a Stream and decode a GIF image
var uri = new Uri(@"http://www.archivearts.com/GIRAFFE2.gif");
GifBitmapDecoder decoder = new GifBitmapDecoder(uri, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
BitmapSource bitmapSource = decoder.Frames[0];
```

Then use the `CopyPixels()` method of the BitmapSource to copy the pixel data into an array. Then convert the array into a string?

I haven't done this, I just took a look at MSDN to get some hints.